# Doctrine merge removes new associations/links

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

We are experiencing some difficulties when updating a detached entity with associations/links. We have a article entity with many to many relations with a category entity.

When adding categories to an existing article by a form and submitting, we get this message:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO articles...Duplicate entry 'test' for key

Which is weird since the entity is an existing one (with id), why is it using insert?

Since the article entity is detached/serialized we tried to merge it, and this time we get no error but no new category links gets inserted into the database. We counted the categories before and after the merge and found out that they are reset to the database state when merging, so if it originally had 2 categories and we added a third the count would be 3 before merge and 2 after. The new category is also a partial entity only containing the id of the category.

Here is the code:

```
    $connection->beginTransaction();

    try {
        // Manage model by doctrine if it's not.
        $modelState = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityState($model);
        if ($modelState !== UnitOfWork::STATE_MANAGED) {
            $model = $entityManager->merge($model); // Strips new categories.
        }

        $entityManager->persist($model);
        $entityManager->flush();
        $connection->commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $connection->rollback();
    }
```

Entities:

```
<entity name="Article" table="articles" repository-class="Doctrine\Repository\BaseRepository">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
        <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>

    <field name="title" type="string" column="title" length="50" nullable="true"/>

    <many-to-many field="categories" target-entity="ArticleCategory" inversed-by="articles">
        <cascade>
            <cascade-persist/>
        </cascade>
        <join-table name="article_category_links">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="article_id" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE"/>
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="article_category_id" referenced-column-name="id" on-delete="CASCADE"/>
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
</entity>

<entity name="ArticleCategory" table="article_categories" repository-class="Doctrine\Repository\BaseRepository">
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
        <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>

    <field name="name" type="string" column="name" length="200" nullable="true"/>

    <many-to-many field="articles" target-entity="Article" mapped-by="categories">
        <cascade>
            <cascade-persist/>
        </cascade>
    </many-to-many>
</entity>
```

### **Update**

This is what we´re doing:

**1. The form $_POST data, the third category is a new one:**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [title] => test
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                )

        )
)
```

**2. The deserialized article (JMS\Serializer):**

```
Article Object
(
    [id:protected] => 1
    [title:protected] => test
    [categories:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => ArticleCategory Object
                (
                    [id:protected] => 1
                    [name:protected] => 
                    [articles:protected] => 
                )

            [1] => ArticleCategory Object
                (
                    [id:protected] => 2
                    [name:protected] => 
                    [articles:protected] => 
                )

            [2] => ArticleCategory Object
                (
                    [id:protected] => 3
                    [name:protected] => 
                    [articles:protected] => 
                )

        )
)
```

**3. Merging of the detached/deserialized article, removes the third category..**

```
$article = $entityManager->merge($article);
```

**4. Flush, updates all the article data, but no link to the third category since it got removed.**

```
$entityManager->flush();
```

**Here are some more examples/tests:**

```
// With attached article and no merging.
// Creates the link to the article, but the category becomes a new one (new id)..
$article = $articleRepository->getById(1)->getItem();
$category = new ArticleCategory();
$category->setId(3); // This doesnt matter since it becomes a new one.
$article->addCategory($category);
$articleRepository->getEntityManager->flush();

// With attached article and merging of category.
// Creates the link to the article but it clears all the category fields..
$article = $articleRepository->getById(1)->getItem();
$category = new ArticleCategory();
$category->setId(3);
$category = $categoryRepository->getEntityManager->merge($category);
$article->addCategory($category);
$articleRepository->getEntityManager->flush();

// With detached and merged article.
// No links no errors, but other article fields gets updated.
$category = new ArticleCategory();
$category->setId(3);
$article->addCategory($category);
echo count($article->getCategories()); // 3
$article = $articleRepository->getEntityManager->merge($article);
echo count($article->getCategories()); // 2, the new one gets removed.
$articleRepository->getEntityManager->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

> "When adding categories to an existing article..."

If it is an existence article you should not do <s>shit</s> this:

```
$model = $entityManager->merge($model);
```

Doctrine lets you to change the state of an object directly if it was load via EntityManager.

> "Which is weird since the entity is an existing one (with id), why is
>   it using insert?"

Because you are calling the persist() method:

```
$entityManager->persist($model);
```

Try something like this:

```
$cat1 = $entityManager->find("ArticleCategory", 1);
$cat2 = $entityManager->find("ArticleCategory", 2);

$model = $entityManager->find("Article", $id);
$model->getCategories()->add($cat1);
$model->getCategories()->add($cat2);

// because the $model exists, you only need to syncronize the changes in the db
$entityManager->flush();
```

## Update

In you need unserialize a model again this shoul do the trick:

```
$detachedEntity = unserialize($model); // some detached entity
$entity = $entityManager->merge($detachedEntity);

// and then, sync the changes in db
$entityManager->flush();
```

Notice the following warning:

> [When you want to serialize/unserialize entities you have to make all entity properties protected, never private. The reason for this is, if you serialize a class that was a proxy instance before, the private variables won’t be serialized and a PHP Notice is thrown.](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities)

Comment: We have successfully tried this approach but the problem occurs when the entity is detached/serialized, and has to be merged.

Comment: @nixxxon, I have edited the answer. Take a look to the warning.

Comment: Thanks @manix, we can't seem to solve it the way we want. I have updated our question with some more examples/tests.

Comment: @nixxxon, could you please show the `Article` and `ArticleCategory` model definition? Looks like you need to cascade the update action.

Comment: the definitions/mappings is in xml in the first post. We managed to get the code working by merging the detached entity when we ask for it (before doing changes), and instead of adding categories with only id, we had to loop the ids and fetch the real categories adding them to the article. Thanks for your  help.

Comment: I had the same issue. In `Article` entity I had configured the relationship with `Category` as `cascade["persists"]`, then I changed to `cascade["all"]` and worked well.